# iOS Calculate Height For Cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a problem with Apple's dynamic resizing cells such that the logic for the layout of my cells isn't as cut and dry as just a few stacked growing UILabels.

As a result, I can't really use the dynamic resizing option they've provided and so I need to manually calculate the height of my cell using NSString boundingRect methods.

That's fine - it works, but I end up needing to store a lot of constants that keep track of my auto layout constraints. I feel like this is counter intuitive to what auto layout is supposed to do for me, so I'm not sure if this is the correct way to implement heightForRowAtIndexPath.

I essentially have to go and copy my constraints into a constant and then use those values in a class method to generate my heights. Apple provides very little internal insight into how UITableViewAutomaticDimension works, but it's clear that the height of the cell is still calculated BEFORE it is laid out. Thus I can't really add any complex logic to it unless I know what methods are called before.

Any ideas on what I should do, or if my approach is ok?

Comment: "the logic for the layout of my cells isn't as cut and dry" - what is the logic?

Comment: boundingRect is not the correct way to calculate a label (or whatever) size, -sizeToFit or -sizeThatFits: are the correct ones

Comment: @kelin I have two labels. If the left label's width cuts into the right label, move the right label below the left label. If the left label takes multiple lines, also move the right label below the left label.

Comment: @Andrea So I need to create an instance of a UILabel to calculate this? It feels a little wasteful, but I'll go for it if its's the proper practice.

Comment: @EricGao the problem is that with boundingRect you only obtain the area to contains the text. UILabel, textview and textfield contain extra padding and the risk is that you are going to cut some glyph. More info here http://doing-it-wrong.mikeweller.com/2012/07/youre-doing-it-wrong-2-sizing-labels.html The right approach is to have cell that you use only for the propose of setting data and getting the size, cache those heights and everything will work

Comment: @Andrea Ok, that's fair reasoning to use sizeThatFits on a UILabel. However, I'm not so sure if it's a good idea to be creating a cell to use only for the purpose of getting the size... seems like unnecessary memory overhead. At that point, you could use a singleton, but even with a singleton I would need to reset the cell every time I wanted to figure out a new height.

Answer (score 0):

The common solution I can offer is to add a height constraint fro your cell and change the constraint according to your needs, whatever they are. `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` will resize cell to the height you specify with this constraint automatically.

Comment: Yes, but where can I modify the height constraint? LayoutSubviews is called too late - the height for the cell is determined by that point. If I set it up right after initialization, the frames for all the subviews are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If your table cell is custom then its easier if you use a method like `configureCell` and pass the indexPath to it from `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and then determine the layout based on the data that you have and see where you want the left and right label to be placed. Once you have done this store the height required in the model or perhaps another array that has the same number of rows as your table and use it to return in `heightForRowAtIndexPath`.

This is easier and gives you flexibility without having to fiddle with too many delegate methods of table view. Centralise your layout logic in one place.
Another alternative is to override layoutSubviews of the table view cell and calculate the height there and store it.

Comment: Thanks, I see that a prototype cell type approach is more common than I would expect.  I like the second method you described better, but that doesn't work. layoutSubviews is called after the height is calculated, so I won't have the height in time.

Comment: If you have a custom cell then perhaps your best option is to use the first approach. If you want to rearrange your labels based on their content then I think you have to calculate the height before hand and return it and then in layoutSubviews you can move the labels to the right or below based on their text size. You are right that layoutSubviews cant be used for calculating the height. The height is already determined at that point.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your tableview cell to be assigned a default height, you can use estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath: available in UITableViewDelegate. As per Apple guidelines:

// Use the estimatedHeight methods to quickly calcuate guessed values which will allow for fast load times of the table.
// If these methods are implemented, the above -tableView:heightForXXX calls will be deferred until views are ready to be displayed, so more expensive logic can be placed there.